# Can a conductor retain charge in vacuum/if it is insulated?

Tags: charge, physics, electricity

Does a charged conductor always lose charge even if it is in vacuum/insulated?

Comment: You should not think of conductors are storing charge. As far as circuit analysis goes, objects do not store charge. The conductor has mobile charges, so when you apply a voltage across it, charges enter on one side and leave on the other side of the conductor. This is also true for resistors, capacitors, inductors, batteries, etc. They do not store any net charge. For every charge that enters, another one leaves.

Comment: @mkeith: Can a [gold leave electroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroscope) not exhibit the storage of a charge?

Comment: It is certainly possible for objects to acquire a net charge in real life. Otherwise we wouldn't have ESD or inkjet printers. But KCL is built on the assumption that circuit elements do not store charge. Many beginners get themselves very confused over this point.

Comment: In the real world nothing is perfect and an electrical charge will leak off.  The remaining question is what lengths will you go to slow that down?  What is your application?  How long do you need to retain the charge?  Remember, this isn't a physics forum - we actually need to build the things we talk about.  And stay in budget!

Comment: I want it stay as long as possible. How long can it hold?

Comment: Charge storage is best demonstrated by the classic Leyden jar demo from a decent H.S. or intro college physics class. Charge it up, disassemble it, ground/short all the metal parts, put it back together, zap something (it's still charged) - the charge is stored on the dielectric (the glass jar, in that case) not the conductors. http://video.mit.edu/watch/dissectible-capacitor-3540/

Comment: Capacitors do not acquire net charge as part of their normal operation. If they did, KCL would be invalid for capacitors. I believe that in the Leyden jar, the energy is stored in the dielectric, which contains immobile charges separated from each other, but the net charge of the dielectric shell (jar) remains neutral. @Ecnerwal

Comment: mkeith, I appreciate your answer. But I have studied right from high school about charging conductors through friction, induction and conduction. Also when electroscope is taken near the conductor, the plate moves showing that the object is charged. Please check the following link about charging a conductor. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-2/Charging-by-Induction

Comment: Let me know if my assumption is wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that physics link. It is perfectly legitimate and accurate. It does not contradict what I am saying in any way, and I am not contradicting what it says in any way.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out real-charge [Electrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret).

You can make an electret by stranding an electric charge inside of a dielectric (insulator). You typically do not use a conductor to hold the charge for practical reasons, but I can't think of any reason why you couldn't if you wanted to.

Depending on how good an insulator you use, the excess charge can persist for decades or longer.